# (Python) Line Break for PyQt5 Menu Bar

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, pyqt5

**Help Needed with PyQt5 Menu Bar:**

I just started getting into PyQt5, and I'm currently making a menu bar for an GUI Application. Below is the code I made for the Menu so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp


class MenuDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

####################################################

        # This Creates the initial Menu Bar
        bar = self.menuBar()

        # This creates the Menu Bar tabs & names them
        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')
        helpme = bar.addMenu('Help')

        # This creates the actions for 'File' section
        new_action = QAction('New File', self)
        new_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')

        open_action = QAction('Open File', self)
        open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')

        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

        save_as_action = QAction('Save as...', self)
        save_as_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Shift+S')

        quit_action = QAction('Quit', self)
        quit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')

        # This creates the actions for 'Edit' section
        undo_action = QAction('Undo', self)
        undo_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Z')

        redo_action = QAction('Redo', self)
        redo_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Y')

        # This creates the actions for "Help" section
        doc_action = QAction('Documentation', self)
        # No Shortcut Needed

        about_action = QAction('About', self)
        # No Shortcut Needed

####################################################

        # This adds actions to Menu Bar under 'File'  Tab
        file.addAction(new_action)
        file.addAction(open_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)
        file.addAction(save_as_action)
        file.addAction(quit_action)

        # This adds actions to Menu Bar under 'Edit'  Tab
        edit.addAction(undo_action)
        edit.addAction(redo_action)

        # This adds actions to Menu Bar under 'Help' Tab
        helpme.addAction(doc_action)
        helpme.addAction(about_action)

        # Events

        # This Sets the initial window size and title
        self.setWindowTitle('My Menu')
        self.resize(750, 500)

        self.show()

####################################################

def quit_trigger(self):
    pass


def selected(self, q):
    pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
menus = MenuDemo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Problem:**

I have the Menu bar displayed, and everything seems to run fine, however there is one thing that is bugging me. Under the 'File' tab of the menu, there is an option called 'Quit'. Above the 'Quit' option, I need to have some sort of line break to seperate that option from the rest of the other options. In Tkinter this is a simple task to do, but I can't seem to find how to do it with PyQt5. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

**P.S:** The menu items are currently just buttons, they dont do anything yet.

Comment: "I can't seem to find how to do it with PyQt5" I often find the documentation of Qt helpful in this regard.  Just go to the API description of the class you are using (`QMenu` in this case) and look what methods are available. For more see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[addSeparator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addSeparator) method of QMenu is just for that occasion:

```
# ...
file.addAction(save_as_action)
file.addSeparator()
file.addAction(quit_action)
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a lot easier than I expected. Works perfect.